# Python reqular expressions non-greedy match

Tags: python, regex

I have this code:

```
import re
a = r'<b>1234</b><b>56text78</b><b>9012</b>'
print re.search(r'<b>.*?text.*?</b>', a).group()
```

and I am trying to match a minimal block between `<b>` and `</b>` which contains 'text' *anywhere* in between. This code is the best I could come up with, but it matches:

```
<b>1234</b><b>56text78</b>
```

while I need:

```
<b>56text78</b>
```

Comment: I would also appreciate an explanation why `.*?text` does not produce a non-greedy match.

Answer (score 2):

instead of `.*` use this

```
print re.search(r'<b>[^<]*text[^<]*</b>', a).group()
```

Here you say that ignore "<" character.

Comment: `*?` is equivalent to `*` in regex.

Comment: @LukeWillis **who said that?**

Comment: `*?` is definitely NOT equivalent to `.*`. If you use my example `<b>.*</b>` will match the whole string, while `<b>.*?<\b>` will only match `<b>12345</b>`.

Comment: if the `?` present just after to `*`,  means it tells the regex engine to do a shortest possible match. Basically `*` will do  a greedy match.

Comment: @AvinashRaj My mistake! You are correct. Well, you learn something new every day, right?

Answer (score 0):

**Why you're getting the output as `<b>1234</b><b>56text78</b>` when using `<b>.*?text.*?</b>` regex?**

Basically regex engine scans the input from left to right. So first it takes the pattern `<b>` from the regex and try to match against the input string. Now the engine scans the input from left to right once it finds the tag `<b>`, it matches that tag. Now the engine takes the second pattern along with the following string `text` that is `.*?text`. Now it matches any character upto the first `text` string. Why i call it as first `text` means , if there are more than one `text` strings after `<b>`, `.*?text` matches upto the first `text` string. So `<b>1234</b><b>56text` will be matched. Now the engine takes the last pattern `.*?</b>` and macthes upto the first `</b>`, so `<b>1234</b><b>56text78</b>` got matched.

When using this `<b>[^<]*text[^<]*</b>` regex, it asserts that the characters before the string (`text`, `</b>`) and after the string (`<b>`, `text`) are any but not of `<` character. So it prevents the engine from matching also the tags.

Answer (score 0):

**Why doesn't `<b>.*?text` produce the desired output?**

This is what regexp engine does:

1. Takes the first character from the search pattern, which is `<`, and
   finds it in the string, then takes the second, then the third, until
   it matches `<b>`.
2. The next step takes the whole `.*?text` pattern and tries to find it
   in the string. That's because `.*?` without the `text` part would
   have no sense, as it would match 0 characters. It matches
   `1234</b><b>56text` part and adds it to `<b>` found in the step 1.

It actually *does* produce a non-greedy output, it's just non-obvious in this case. If the string was:

```
`<b>1234</b><b>56text78text</b><b>9012</b>`
```

then the greedy `'<b>.*text'` match would be:

```
<b>1234</b><b>56text78text
```

and the non-greedy one `'<b>.*?text'` would produce the one I was getting:

```
<b>1234</b><b>56text
```

So to answer the the initial question, the correct solution will be to exclude the '<>' characters from the search:

```
import re
a = r'<b>1234</b><b>56text78</b><b>9012</b>'
print re.search(r'<b>[^<>]*text.*?</b>', a).group()
```